# 2D array to check if array is sorted in ascending order or not

Tags: arrays, recursion, 2d

```
// Recursive approach to check if an Array is sorted or not

class CheckSorted {
// Function that returns 0 if a pair is found unsorted
static int arraySortedOrNot(int arr[], int n)
{
    // Array has one or no element or the rest are already checked 
    if (n == 1 || n == 0)
        return 1;

    // Unsorted pair found
    if (arr[n - 1] < arr[n - 2])
        return 0;

    // Last pair was sorted ,Keep on checking
    return arraySortedOrNot(arr, n - 1);
}


public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int arr[] = { 20, 23, 23, 45, 78, 88 };
    int n = arr.length;
    if (arraySortedOrNot(arr, n) != 0)
        System.out.println("The given array is sorted in the ascending order");
    else
        System.out.println("The given array is not sorted in the ascending order");
}
}
```

I am checking if the given 1D array is in ascending order or not using recursion. How do I do the same for 2D arrays? Explanation with a code will be helpful

Comment: Can you give an example of a sorted 2D array?

Comment: {{3,4,5,6},{7,8,9,10}}

Answer (score 0):

(First understand that recursion is usually a bad approach in the real world. Mathematically, it is beautiful; practically, it can overload the call stack and crash your program. In real-world applications, iterate, don't recurse.)

There is more than one way to adapt you code for a 2D array. Perhaps the most elegant is to write a function that converts a single index into a pair of indices. For example, considering the array

```
3 4 5 6
7 8 9 10
```

The value at (1, 2) is 9. This is the 6th element in the order. We want a function that will convert:

```
0 -> (0, 0)
1 -> (0, 1)
...
6 -> (1, 2)
7 -> (1, 3)
```

Let's call the function `convertCoords`. Once that's working, we make a small adjustment in your `arraySortedOrNot`:

```
if (n == 1 || n == 0)
    return 1;

// Given n and the dimensions of the array, convertCoords can calculate the
// indices j and k.
// So we calculate j1 and k1 using n-1, and j2 and k2 using n-2.

if (arr[j1][k1] < arr[j2][k2])
    return 0;

// Last pair was sorted ,Keep on checking
return arraySortedOrNot(arr, n - 1);
```